# Configuring ssh in cygwin

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I am a newbie to `cygwin`, I am trying to configure `ssh` and was finally checking my connection, I am getting this message when I `ssh`:

```
Admin@admin-PC ~  
$ ssh localhost  
Last login: Thu Sep 17 15:06:15 2015 from: ::1
```

What does `from: ::1` mean?

I am not getting my host name displayed there. The actual output must be something like `Last login: Thu Sep 17 15:06:15 2015 from: ::admin-pc`.

Why am I not getting this? Is there any error in my configuration?

Comment: *"The actual output must be something like `Last login: Thu Sep 17 15: 06: 15 2015 from: ::admin-pc`"*; why do you need the output to be in that format?

Comment: @bertieb the tutorial which i am going through for installing hadoop gives output similar to that. i am just checking my correctness to proceed with the tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what does "from ::1" mean?

::1 is the IPv6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1. Basically just localhost